# What are Memrise's advantages?

Tags: learning-methods, memrise

I want to use Memrise to learn languages, but I do not know [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com)'s advantages. What are [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com)'s advantages?
I accepted an answer, but If someone posted a good answer here, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! Can you edit your question to clarify which aspect of language learning you are most interested in? Also, you don't need to quote Wikipedia in this question.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I edited my question. Can I improve more?

Comment: That is more specific, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I hope we can help you.  But first, we need to narrow the question a bit more. Practically any learning method *can* be effective. So when addressing these questions about effectiveness, we require a specific approach. As an example, "What are the greatest strengths of Memrise?" or "What are the drawbacks to Memrise?" would either be a great question. If you want, you could ask both, each in a separate post. Once you've chosen a direction with the question, please flag the question for moderator attention, and we can re-open it.

Comment: @Flimzy The question had previously been reworded as, "Is Memrise effective for learning words?". Even though the title had not been reworded, was that really too broad? (There has been research on the effectiveness of Memrise for learning vocabulary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me (according to its precedence):

- it is free (at least its basic functions),
- it has a huge amount of
  material and you always can find something for your knowledge level,
- it uses mnemonic technique to help remember words and it is really
  invaluable in learning languages like Japanese or Chinese,
- you can
  create your own "courses" or at least create your own mem  (mnemonic
  picture that should help you remember word or phrase).

Answer (score 1):

After i posted my question, I searched.

- The vocabulary lists on this site include memory cues with their words, to give you tricks and mnemonics to make it much less likely you'll forget the words. - lifehacker
- In neuroscience, It has been designed to become effective to learn language.
- You can test.

The reference:

- [lifehacker - How to Successfully Learn a New Language This Year](http://lifehacker.com/5974670/how-to-successfully-learn-a-new-language-this-year)

Answer (score -1):

Advertisement said that project is developed by neuroscientis and polyglot. **But they develop only platform!**

Unfortunately Memrise materials is made by **volunteers with variety of skills**. And you should investigate what practice from 100...00 available courses is satisfied your needs ))

Another point you should conclude that some learners suggest to build learning cards for SRS yourself ([Mistake #1: Not Making your Own Cards](http://skillcookbook.com/flashcards/)). For example you may waste your time on unimportant topic/words.

I uses Anki/AnkiDroid software in order to be independent from platform provider and build word cards myself, but previously have experience with Duolingo & Memrise.

Duolingo worked for me for 2 month to build vocabulary. Next I needed to resign because its level became not enough good for me. Memrise courses do not satisfy my quality assumptions and I do not like proprietary platforms.